# mvc routing - Passing data to a display controller from the Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a route like the following:

```
/Company/1234/Contact/3456
```

The general pattern for my routes is that strings are actions/areas and numerics are the records ids.

In the Contact controller (action{edit}) I want to pass in the id from the company and the contact. 
Is there a way in the framework to get that information? Or do I need to parse all numeric values in the route in order to know which is what?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an other question I asked [MVC3 Routing - Routes that builds on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647680/mvc3-routing-routes-that-builds-on-each-other)

The solution would be to name my routes correctly, with each id having a unique name.
Company would be CompanyId, contact would be ContactId.

```
/Company/{CompnayId}/Contact/{ContactId}
```

Then in the controller method the signature could look like:

```
ActionView Edit(int CompanyId, int ContactId))
{
...
}
```